# Lifetime error for method returning iterator

Tags: rust

I am facing a weird lifetime compilation error while trying to compile following simple XOR encryption Rust code.

```
pub struct Encrypt<'a> {
    key:&'a[u8],
    current_index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Encrypt<'a> {
    pub fn new<T: ?Sized + AsRef<[u8]>>(key: &'a T) -> Encrypt<'a> {
        Encrypt { key: key.as_ref(), current_index: 0 }
    }

    pub fn encrypt<T, U>(&'a mut self, data: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8>
                where T: IntoIterator<Item = U>, U: std::borrow::Borrow<u8> {
        let iter = data.into_iter().map(|b| {
            let val = b.borrow() ^ self.key[self.current_index];
            self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % self.key.len();
            val
        });
        iter
    }
}
```

I am getting following bompilation error:

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
8  | impl<'a> Encrypt<'a> {
   |      -- hidden type `Map<<T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter, [closure@src/lib.rs:36:41: 40:10]>` captures the lifetime `'a` as defined here
...
41 |         iter
```

This is really strange because the method encrypt() does not return any reference, still the compiler appears to be associating the lifetime of self with it.

Comment: `.map()` makes a lazy iterator, thus the closure that is used in it has to capture all the objects used inside. In particular you use `&'a self` in it to access `self.key` and `self.current_index`, so the returning iterator is actually  tied to this reference and its lifetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem that can arise from incorrect lifetime annotations. The issue is that you're binding the returned iterator's lifetime to the lifetime of `self` which is `'a`. But you don't care about the lifetime of `self`, you only care about the lifetime of the reference you're borrowing to it, `&mut self`, let's call that lifetime `'s`.

Now we just need to tell the compiler:

```
impl<'a> Encrypt<'a> {
    pub fn encrypt<'s, T, U>(&'s mut self, data: T) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 's
    //             ^^         ^^                                                ^^^^
    // tie the return value's lifetime to the lifetime for which we burrow `self` 
    // instead of the whole lifetime of `self`.
    where
        T: IntoIterator<Item = U> + 's,
        //                        ^^^^
        // That'll transitively require this bound
        U: std::borrow::Borrow<u8>,
    {
        let iter = data.into_iter().map(|b| {
            let val = b.borrow() ^ self.key[self.current_index];
            self.current_index = (self.current_index + 1) % self.key.len();
            val
        });
        iter
    }
}
```